How to change currency format in PowerBI even if its in whole number format
enter image description here
I am unable to remove the currency format from the column. I can see the format in transform data as whole number but when i try to open in a chart, it is showing currency.enter image description here
I am expecting to remove the currency format and make it as a text format. Please refer the screenshot.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you need to change the data type to TEXT first, then you can do the replace value.

or you can create a new column in PQ
="Q" & Number.ToText([Qtr])


